# Stylesheet Not Being Read Correctly by Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm having issues getting a stylesheet to display correctly in Firefox. It looks fine in Chrome and IE, however none of the styles seem to be applied in Firefox. Any suggestions?

Here's the link: http://www.bearfootmgmt.com

Answer (score 4):

I checked `style.css` and there's a rather malformed rule here:

```
$toppart {
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
    /* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
    background: #fff) -moz-linear-gradient(top;
    /* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#DAE4EE, endColorstr=#FFFFFFFF);
    /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progidDXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr#DAE4EE, endColorstr#FFFFFFFF)";
}
```

I ran your site through the [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bearfootmgmt.com%2F) and it also found this misspelled selector:

```
#maincontent a:hovvr {
    color:#ce0101;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Yes I just noticed that rule as well, and removing it fixed the problem. Strange thing is I don't really know where it came from.